# Mixed Content using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, https, zk, mixed-content

I use gmaps show Map in my web site.

**MY CODE**

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
  <script type="text/javascript" content="zk.googleAPIkey='***MyKey***'" />
    <gmaps id="gmaps" zoom="${initialZoom}" lat="${initialLatitude}" lng="${initialLongitude}" width="100%" height="350px" showSmallCtrl="false"   >
    <gmarker id="marker"  content="" visible="${false}" />
    </gmaps>
</div>
```

In my local server work fine but in my productive server with **https** don't work and i have this error:

**EXCEPTION**

```
zk.wpd:20 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.domain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=***MyKey***'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.loadScript @ zk.wpd:20
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up Google Script with `//` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solvel my problem remplace `zk.googleAPIkey=****key***` for `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****key***`

The problem is this tag `zk.googleAPIkey`  because your value is `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?` the problem is the `http`

**Before**

```
<script type="text/javascript" content="zk.googleAPIkey='***MyKey***'" />
```

**After**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***key***" />
```

Answer (score 5):

added the following and solved my problem

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"/>
```

in head

Answer (score 0):

From [ZK demo of google maps](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/reporting/google_map) :

```
<gmaps version="3.26" id="gmaps" width="520px" height="400px" showSmallCtrl="true" protocol="https">
```

Can you try adding the protocol property?

Comment: can you provide feedback?